# Shell script that can call a binary

Tags: c, shell, ssh

I want to ssh a server to run a binary compiled from a C program but apparently ssh can only send bash command.

I was thinking to make a shell script to run the binary so I can call the script via ssh. Is that a doable?

So normally this would work

```
$./mycprogram
```

But I am finding this doesn't work

```
$ssh user@node ./mycprogram
```

While other bash command via same ssh does work

What's the right way to call `mycprogram` from other server (via ssh)?

Comment: what's running a c object? do you mean running a c program? compiling one? something else?

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Does the program reside immediately in the home directory? If not, you must provide its path.

Comment: what message do you get? what's the output of `echo $?` after the failed run?

Answer (score 1):

If by "C object" you mean "a C program", it must be compiled before it can be run. There *are* C interpreters, but most C programs are written to be compiled.

If the program has been compiled, you can run it just like you can run any other program, by calling it by name from the bash script. Many regular "shell commands" are in fact compiled C programs (things like `ls`, `cp` and so on).

Of course you need to make sure that the binary (the compiled C program) is available in the target machine, and that it's located in the proper place.

Comment: I am trying to run the compiled via ssh. Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the directory.

E. g. If you ssh into the other host, change the directory with `cd mydir` and then do `./myprogram`, you have to take care for this by using

```
ssh myhost mydir/myprogram
```

so that the file can be found.

Comment: Yes it was directory I didnt specify. But specifying the directory like your suggestion also doesnt work. I end up moving the object to root which will involve a lot of other change. I find this as another weird thing about Linux. Thanks for all your answers

Comment: @EmmaAhmadSirajudin This has nothing to do with "weird Linux"; probably you still have done something wrong. Normally what you describe should definitely work; I do this every day. Maybe you have made a mistake when specifying the path; note that `/path/to/wherever` is different from `path/to/wherever`.